# Same application works for one android API but not another

Tags: android, emulation

When I run my application in android 1.5 it works great, but when i just change the target to android 3.0 i get stuck at:

Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

I didn't change  a single thing in my code...

Could you please tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: That's a line in logcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

That is not from your app. That is from the emulator, which is taking too long to start up.

> Could you please tell me what could be the reason?

The Android 3.0 emulator is extremely slow. Bump the "device RAM" setting to 1024MB in your AVD if you can spare the RAM, as that appears to help a bit. Otherwise, there is nothing you can really do.

Comment: thank you so much! i increased the device ram and had to restart eclipse for it to work.